# Is it possible to use Spring Security – Kerberos Extension to make soap calls to Kerberos protected service?

Tags: web-services, spring, security, kerberos, spnego

Is it possible to use Spring Security – Kerberos Extension to make soap calls to Kerberos protected service ? We have Wss4jSecurityInterceptor for Spring-ws , but if the soap client want to send kerberos token , we don;t have any kerberosSecurityInterceptor ? Is there a way to do this using Spring Security – Kerberos Extension? Please advise?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No, that extension if for Web auth only.